How can I keep my indoor basil plant happy?
I bought a basil plant from Trader Joe’s in hopes of always having access to fresh basil! However it seems I use it for one dinner and then it starts to get super “droopy”. Any tips on keeping an indoor basil plant happy?

Basil doesn't have drupes.  What do you mean?

The OP means wilting

Please post a photo

You might want to advise where you are.   The basil I bought (which came in soil) from the supermarket and had in a small pot lasted for a long time just sitting on my windowsill in a tray, and being thoroughly watered (till the water came out the bottom) every few days.  My Windowsill was South Facing and I am in the southern hemisphere, and I'm in the equivalent of hardiness zone 9b)

Its difficult without a picture, but if a plant is drooping it is often because of lack of water - although ironically overwatering it can also cause similar looking issues in many plants - not sure about Basil.
